# Function that splits a list of list into first and last names, returns none for no surname

Tags: python, list

A function that has one argument list of full name strings and returns a list of same length where each element contains first and last name where a last name is not present it should return None.

Using this as input:
`['Michael jackson', 'rock', 'clark kent', 'snoop']`

function would return:
`[['Michael ', 'jackson'], ['rock', None], ['clark ', 'kent'], ['snoop', None]]`
Update:
What I have so far gives me the right output but just would like clarification on whether this is an optimal way or can it be cleaned up in anyway.

```
def name_processing1(list_of_names):
x = []
for name in list_of_names:
    y = name.split()
    x.append(y)
    if len(y) < 2:
        y.append(None)
return x
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have updated my post with my most recent solution,

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for you use case,

```
list_of_names = ['Michael jackson', 'rock', 'clark kent', 'snoop']

def name_processing(list_of_names):
    List = []
    for name in list_of_names:
        split_list = name.split()
        if len(split_list)<2:
            split_list.insert(1, 'None')
        List.append(split_list)
    return List

print(name_processing(list_of_names))
```

The output is,

```
[['Michael', 'jackson'], ['rock', 'None'], ['clark', 'kent'], ['snoop', 'None']]
```

I hope this will help you.